# Binary file and "* text eol=lf"

Tags: git, git-config, line-endings

I have created a random binary file:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=random bs=1 count=1024
md5 random
```

The md5 hash is c4074ec24509750f4278c244426f7ba7 and it contains `LF` characters.

I have a `.gitattributes` file with

```
* text eol=lf
```

Meaning that every path has end-of-line normalization enabled, and working dir checkout is `LF` endings (`eol=lf`).

I have `core.autocrlf = false` in my git config
and have added and commited the file:

```sh
git add -A
git commit -a -m "first"
git show --format=raw $(git ls-files -s random | cut -d " " -f 2) | md5
```

The outputed md5 hash of the corresponding blob object has not changed. Why is that. I expected a change since the file is cleary marked as text by the `.gitattributes` , and `git add` should have eol normalized this binary file (which is nonsense). 
But why did nothing happen?

Comment: `eol=lf` merely *replaces* `\r\n` with `\n`-only when `git add`ing a file. If the input file has no `\r\n` sequences, nothing gets replaced. With only 1024 random bytes a `\r\n` pair is unlikely.